# Matlab: changing zero-one index vector to proper index vector

Tags: matlab, indices

Suppose an index vector in binary like below

**Input**

```
1 1 0 0 1 0 1

1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

**Intended output**

```
1 2 5 7
```

which denotes `n`th number to be chosen. So I want to change `1 1 0 0 1 0 1` to `1 2 5 7`, is there some easy way for this?

Comment: I have earlier done `vals=1:length(dataStructure); vals(indicesBinary)` but looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is using the function `find(indicesBinary)`

Comment: Ofc, why I keep forgetting this...+1.

Comment: :). Just remember that if you want to use it for indexing another vector, using find as an intermediate step is actually slower than using the indicesBinary directly

Comment: You mean it is better to do `vals=1:length(dataStructure); vals(logical(indicesBinary))`?

Comment: Not at all. Find is more efficient if you want to do this. But if you want to use vals or indiciesBinary to select values from a different vector, using indiciesBinary directly will be faster.

Comment: so 
    `actualVals = dataStructure(indicesBinary);`
gives the same result but is faster than
    `actualVals = dataStructure(find(indicesBinary));`. So if index positions is what you want, use `find`. If you actually want to index, use indicesBinary directly (but cast them to logical if they aren't already)

Comment: Now I cannot understand `"if you want to do this"`: which version is faster or does it depend?

Comment: So let's say you have some vector `v = [13,63,34,1];` and you have a binary index vector `b_idx = [0, 1, 1, 0];` If you want to index v with b_idx, you do `sel_v = v(b_idx);`. The output is sel_v = [63,34] and is fast+. If you instead want to know the indexes that b_idx correspond to (as posed in the question), you do `idx = find(b_idx);`. The output is idx = [2,3]. You can then off course also do `sel_v = v(idx);` to get sel_v = [63,34]. Doing `find` and then indexing  with `idx` to get [63,34] is also fast, but not as fast as using `b_idx` directly. Hope that clears things up

Answer (score 2):

If you actually want to use your output to index another vector, do it directly.

You just need to transform your binary vector to `logical`

```
A = [1 1 0 0 1 0 1];    %assuming its double
B = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7];

C = B( logical(A) )

C =

     1     2     5     7
```